# Generic function with type bounds

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a generic function which takes a generic container that implements "++", however I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
def pagedRequest[A, C[_] <: Iterable](url: String, accumulator: C[A])(parser: (WSResponse) => C[A]): Future[Either[Result, C[A]]] = {
  WS.url(url).get().flatMap { response =>
    response.status match {
      case OK =>
        val data = accumulator ++ parser(response)

        (response.json \ "paging" \ "next").asOpt[String] match {
          case None => Future.successful(Right(data))
          case Some(next) => pagedRequest(next, data)(parser)
        }

      case _ =>
        Future.successful(Left(ProxiedResult(response)))
    }
  }
}
```

The type of "data" keeps being Iterable[A], instead of C[A].

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `++` operator is taking an implicit `CanBuildFrom`, which is typed to `Iterable`.

From `TraversableLike` and `Iterable` in the Scala source:

```
  def ++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    if (that.isInstanceOf[IndexedSeqLike[_, _]]) b.sizeHint(this, that.seq.size)
    b ++= thisCollection
    b ++= that.seq
    b.result
  }

  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Iterable[A]] = ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]
```

So the result of `++` is `That` which is typed to `Iterable`. I don't think you're able to do what you want to do here without casting as ugly as that may be...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this seems to be with explicit typecast.

A minimalist example:

1) without typecast, we get Iterable:

```
scala> def addup[A, C[A] <: Iterable[A]](a:C[A],b:C[A])=a ++ b
addup: [A, C[A] <: Iterable[A]](a: C[A], b: C[A])Iterable[A]

scala> addup(List(2,3,4,5),List(4,5,6,7))
res3: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

2) with typecast, we get C[A]:

```
scala> def addupC[A, C[A] <: Iterable[A]](a:C[A],b:C[A])=(a ++ b).asInstanceOf[C[A]]
addupC: [A, C[A] <: Iterable[A]](a: C[A], b: C[A])C[A]

scala> addupC(List(2,3,4,5),List(4,5,6,7))
res4: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

(A similar issue occurs when working with libraries like Slick, by the way.)

In your case, you'd have to try this::

```
def pagedRequest[A, C[A] <: Iterable[A]](url: String, accumulator: C[A])(parser: (WSResponse) => C[A]): Future[Either[Result, C[A]]] = {
  WS.url(url).get().flatMap { response =>
    response.status match {
      case OK =>
        val data = (accumulator ++ parser(response)).asInstanceOf[C[A]]

        (response.json \ "paging" \ "next").asOpt[String] match {
          case None => Future.successful(Right(data))
          case Some(next) => pagedRequest(next, data)(parser)
        }

      case _ =>
        Future.successful(Left(ProxiedResult(response)))
    }
  }
}
```